# Guys, I was using codemagic to automate publishing in flutter, but it stopped working

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, cd

I was using codemagic to automate publishing in flutter, but it stopped working for ios, publishing works on our machines, but it stopped working on codemagic. Does anyone know if there was a change?

Comment: verify if the flutter local version is the same in codemagic.

Comment: What's the error output?